# Fill array based on sparse information

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following sparsity structure to describe the underlying dense array `A`:

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([1, 5, 2, 3])
```

`a` contains `1` whenever `A` changes the value. `b` contains the new value whenever `A` changes value. That is, my example of `a`, `b` yields the following array:

```
A = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

How can I efficiently recover `A` given the sparse information? I'd be particularly interested in a solution that can be scaled up when `b` is n-dimensional.

---

In 2d, we would have the same `a`, but

```
bb = np.array([[1, 5, 2, 2], [2, -1, 0, 1]])
```

which yields

```
AA = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how it would work with an 2+-dimensional `b` array

Comment: Could the first element of `a` be zero? If so, what's the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar Right now I have hard-coded the first one to be a `1`. I can change that to be a zero if it makes it easier. In either case, `A[0] == b[0]` is expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple really with `cumsum`. Use `cumsum` to get those *intervaled* indices and then index into the data array.

Thus, for `1D` data -

```
idx = a.cumsum(-1)-1
out = b[idx]
```

For `2D` data -

```
out = bb[np.arange(bb.shape[0])[:,None],idx]
```

For generic `n-dim` data, simply use `np.take` to index along the last axis and thus would cover for generic `n-dim` cases, like so -

```
np.take(b_ndarray,idx,axis=-1)
```

**Sample runs**

```
In [80]: a  # sparse array that defines the intervals/indices
Out[80]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])

In [81]: b # 1D data array
Out[81]: array([1, 5, 2, 3])

In [82]: bb  # 2D data array
Out[82]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  2,  2],
       [ 2, -1,  0,  1]])

In [93]: idx = a.cumsum(-1)-1 # Get the intervaled indices

In [94]: idx
Out[94]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])

In [84]: np.take(b,idx,axis=-1) # output for 1D data
Out[84]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3])

In [85]: np.take(bb,idx,axis=-1)  # output for 2D data
Out[85]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5,  5,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1]])
```

Let's test out for some random `3D` data too -

```
In [89]: bbb = np.random.randint(-4,5,(2,3,4))

In [90]: bbb
Out[90]: 
array([[[-1,  0,  0,  4],
        [ 0, -1,  3,  1],
        [ 1, -4, -3,  1]],

       [[-1, -4,  1, -4],
        [-3, -2,  0, -2],
        [-4, -1, -2, -4]]])

In [91]: np.take(bbb,idx,axis=-1)
Out[91]: 
array([[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  3,  3,  3,  1],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3,  1]],

       [[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -4, -4,  1,  1,  1, -4],
        [-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -2,  0,  0,  0, -2],
        [-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -4]]])
```

---

**Runtime test**

Other approach(es) -

```
def diff_repeat_1d(a, b): # @Kasramvd's soln for 1D
    inds = np.concatenate((np.where(a)[0], [a.size]))
    durations = np.diff(inds)
    return np.repeat(b, durations)

def diff_repeat_2d(a, b): # @Kasramvd's soln for 2D
    inds = np.concatenate((np.where(a)[0], [a.size]))
    durations = np.diff(inds)
    return np.repeat(bb, durations, axis=1)
```

Timings on 1D data -

```
In [199]: a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
     ...: b = np.array([1, 5, 2, 3])
     ...: 

In [200]: a = np.tile(a,100000)
     ...: b = np.tile(b,100000)
     ...: 

In [201]: %timeit diff_repeat_1d(a, b) # @Kasramvd's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 8.42 ms per loop

In [202]: %timeit np.take(b,a.cumsum()-1,axis=-1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.53 ms per loop
```

Timings on 2D data -

```
In [203]: bb = np.array([[1, 5, 2, 2], [2, -1, 0, 1]])

In [204]: bb = np.tile(bb,100000)

In [206]: %timeit diff_repeat_2d(a, bb) # @Kasramvd's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop

In [207]: %timeit np.take(bb,a.cumsum()-1,axis=-1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.58 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is there a solution that scales to N dimensions?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, added!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
In [45]: inds = np.concatenate((np.where(a)[0], [a.size]))

In [46]: durations = np.diff(inds)

In [47]: np.repeat(b, durations)
Out[47]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

For 2d array you just need to pass the axis to the `repeat` function:

```
In [49]: np.repeat(bb, durations, axis=1)
Out[49]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5,  5,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1]])
```